# Img appearing out of order when placed in between links

Tags: html, css, image, position

I'm trying to create a paginator which inserts an ellipsis in the middle. My issue is the ellipsis ends up at the end of the row instead of in the middle like I'm placing it in the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div>
    <div class="pagination">
        <a href="?page=1">1</a>
        <a href="?page=2">2</a>
        <a href="?page=3">3</a>
        <img src="/static/svg/ellipsis-h-solid.svg" style="width: 15px">
        <a href="?page=13">13</a>
        <a href="?page=14">14</a>
        <a href="?page=15" class="active">15</a>
    </div>
    <p style="margin-left: 10px;">30 trades</p>
</div>
```

[image: Ellipsis out of order]

EDIT:
I also tried setting `display: inline` and `display: inline-block` but it still appears at the end

```
<div class="pagination">
    <a href="?page=1" >1</a>
    <a href="?page=2" >2</a>
    <a href="?page=3" class="active">3</a>
    <img src="/static/svg/ellipsis-h-solid.svg" style="width: 15px; display: inline;">
    <a href="?page=13" >13</a>
    <a href="?page=14" >14</a>
    <a href="?page=15" >15</a>
</div>
```

Comment: set `style="display:inline"` or `style="display:inline-block"` for the img tag

Comment: Hey Dickens! Thanks for the suggestion. I tried both but the ellipsis still ended up at the end unfortunately. Any other ideas?

Comment: ellipsis should be naturally placed between 3 and 13, check the style you've applied and insert the relevant css in the question

Comment: in my computer the img appears in 4th place, I strongly believe your anchor has good previous styling which disturbs the img placement, I beleive your anchor is sorted using either javascript of CSS style

Comment: I see. I did place this div within a flex-box so perhaps that's it. I'll take a look into it. Thanks Dickens! If you post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my computer the img appears in 4th place, I strongly believe your anchor has good previous styling which disturbs the img placement, I beleive your anchor is sorted using either javascript or CSS style

please check that you have any CSS style like this, add the img tag also for that CSS

```
{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
}
```

may be try to manually give order like this example (optional)

```
:nth-child(1) { order: 2; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.pagination,
.pagination img {
  float: none;
}
```

I think you should check the float property.